# evaluate int column from two tables based on id columns, update its sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables in my Postgres DB.

Table 1:

```
car_id   Price      
176        0
39         1
86         4
2          0
```

Table 2:

```
car_id   Price      
176        2
39         1
86         5
2          0
```

I want to compare the two tables based on match on car_id and sum up the price column and update table 1 with the newly added sum.

Table 1 after the update should have this output:

```
car_id   Price      
176        2
39         2
86         9
2          0
```

Here is what I attempted:

```
UPDATE table1  
SET price = (
                SELECT table2.price
                FROM table2
                WHERE table2.car_id = table1.car_id
              )
WHERE exists
(
   SELECT table2.price
   FROM table2
   WHERE table2.car_id = table1.car_id
)
```

I understand this is just updating the values from table1 to reflect table2, how would I go about getting the sum of price and updating table1 with that new sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
SET Price = Price + t2.Price
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.car_id = t2.car_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!